# Convert Binary to int without Convert.ToInt32

Tags: .net-micro-framework

I need to convert binary `10100101` to an integer in C# without using Convert.ToInt64(bin,2), I'm working with the .net micro framework. When I use `int i = Convert.ToInt32(byt, 2);` an exception is thrown with the rather unhelpfull message of:

```
 #### Exception System.ArgumentException - 0x00000000 (1) ####
    #### Message: 
    #### System.Convert::ToInt32 [IP: 000d] ####
    #### TRNG.Program::loop [IP: 0047] ####
    #### TRNG.Program::Main [IP: 0011] ####
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: Well, what is the type of `byt`?

Comment: Do you mean you need to convert the string "10100101"?

Comment: string byt = "10101001";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly faster than Femaref's option, as it doesn't require a pesky method call, and uses OR instead of ADD just for fun:

```
public static int ParseBinary(string input)
{
    // Count up instead of down - it doesn't matter which way you do it
    int output = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == '1')
        {
            output |= 1 << (input.Length - i - 1);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

You may want to:

- Check that the length is less than 32 to start with
- Check that every character is '0' or '1'

Just for LOLs, here's a LINQ version:

```
public static int ParseBinary(string input)
{
    return input.Select((c, index) => new { c, index })
        .Aggregate(0, (current, z) => current | (z.c - '0') << 
                                        (input.Length - z.index - 1));
}
```

Or neater yet:

```
public static int ParseBinary(string input)
{
    return return input.Aggregate(0, (current, c) => (current << 1) | (c - '0'));
}
```

Comment: darn shifts, should've seen that one coming (and I just had binary number formats in university, should've known it anyway). Beautiful solution.

Comment: length is less than or equal to 8 for a byte

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "10101001";
int output = 0;
for(int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(input[7-i] == '1')
    output += Math.Pow(2, i);
}
```

in general:

```
string input = "10101001";
int output = 0;
for(int i = (input.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(input[input.Length - i] == '1')
    output += Math.Pow(2, i);
}
```

Comment: Your code (2nd block) as is, does not work you need to make some casts: change input[input.Length - i] to input[input.Length - i].ToString() and Math.Pow(2, i) to (int)System.Math.Pow(2, i) however after doing this it thows:Exception System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException - CLR_E_OUT_OF_RANGE on the int.Parse... line.  I was able to get it to stop throwing exceptions but then it only output 255 when the input was not 11111111

Comment: Also for the sake of performace you can drop the int.Parse and change that line to `if(input[input.Length - i].ToString() == "1")`

Comment: @Unknwntech: Calling ToString on each character doesn't sound like much of an optimization to me - character comparisons FTW :)